# Postgres Query Improvement needed

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have to improvement this query:

```
SELECT pt.equip, pt.date, pt.cod,  
(  
SELECT pt2.date  
FROM "TABLE" pt2  
WHERE 1=1  
AND pt2.equip = pt.equip  
AND CAST(pt2.date AS DATE) between '2015/12/01' AND '2015/12/02'  
AND pt2.cod in (17, 84, 85)  
AND pt2.date > pt.date  
ORDER BY pt2.date  
LIMIT 1  
)  
FROM "TABLE" pt   
WHERE pt.cod is not null  
AND pt.equip IN (2,3,8,7)  
AND CAST(pt.date AS DATE) between '2015/12/01' AND '2015/12/02'  
AND pt.cod in (16, 81, 82)
```

The subquery is the same table of the main query.
The **cod** column defines the initial period in the first query, and **cod** defines the end of the second query.
How to make a query with the columns **equip**, **dateInitial** (first query), **dateEnd** (second query)???

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Please edit this into the question - it's impossible to understand it in the comments, without any formatting.

Answer (score 2):

One approach to this query is to do a `LEFT JOIN` between the tables and then use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pt.equip, pt.date, pt.cod) pt.*, pt2.*
FROM "TABLE" pt LEFT JOIN
     "TABLE" pt2
     ON pt2.equip = pt.equip AND
        CAST(pt2.date AS DATE) between '2015/12/01' AND '2015/12/02' AND
        pt2.cod in (17, 84, 85) AND
        pt2.date > pt.date
WHERE pt.cod is not null AND
      pt.equip IN (2,3,8,7) AND
      CAST(pt.date AS DATE) between '2015/12/01' AND '2015/12/02' AND
      pt.cod in (16, 81, 82)  
ORDER BY pt.equip, pt.date, pt.cod, pt2.date DESC;
```

Since version 9.3, Postgres has also supported lateral joins, which allow the subquery to be in the `FROM` clause, thereby making it easier to choose multiple columns from its result set.